# Adjust Xcode Build setting value based on environment variable

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I have a user defined build setting at the project level:
[image: user defined build setting]

Which is fed into the Other Swift flags build setting also at the project level:
[image: Other Swift flags build setting]

This causes the compiler to emit a warning when any function takes longer than 1000 ms to compile. The problem is that CI is much slower than our dev machines, so on our dev machines we would like it to be more like 300 ms, and on CI 2000+ ms, or maybe even just disabled. We run with warnings as errors, so if the CI which is shared machines goes slow this often causes the build to fail.

When running on CI there is a `CI` environment variable that is set, so I'd like to change the value of the `LONG_SWIFT_COMPILE_LIMIT_MS` build setting if CI is set or not. How can I do this? I tried adding:

```
if [ -z ${CI+x} ]; then
    # Not running on CI
    setenv LONG_SWIFT_COMPILE_LIMIT_MS 300
else
    # Running on CI
    setenv LONG_SWIFT_COMPILE_LIMIT_MS 2000
fi
```

as a prebuild script on the scheme, but that didn't work.

Comment: I think it should work if the environment variable is set when `xcodebuild` is invoked. Alternatively, you can pass `LONG_SWIFT_COMPILE_LIMIT_MS=2000` as an argument to `xcodebuild`.

Comment: `CI` is set before `xcodebuild` is invoked. But using my bash script above, the `LONG_SWIFT_COMPILE_LIMIT_MS` variable isn't found by Xcode when running it locally. Not sure how to run a script earlier then the scheme pre-build action.

Comment: Ah, that worked. In the CI's settings it has an area for additional `xcodebuild` flags so adding `LONG_SWIFT_COMPILE_LIMIT_MS=2000` there works. Then the user defined `LONG_SWIFT_COMPILE_LIMIT_MS=300` in the project file is used only locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify build setting overrides on the `xcodebuild` command line by adding `<setting>=<value>` arguments. For your case, `LONG_SWIFT_COMPILE_LIMIT_MS=2000`.

This can't be done by an Xcode scheme pre-build script.